# Regular Expression to select everything before and up to a particular text

Tags: regex

I am trying to use a regular expression to find a part of a string and select everything up to that string.  So for example if my string is `this/is/just.some/test.txt/some/other`, I want to search for `.txt` and when I find it select everything before and up to `.txt`.

Comment: By "select everything before and up to .txt", did you mean "select everything before and including .txt"? If so, the answers so far are incorrect. Otherwise, "before" and "up to" are redundant.

Comment: @Jim L - I'd say he means up to the end of .txt, not up to the beginning of .txt

Comment: What could be the solution in order to capture only the complete word before .txt? In this case "test".

Answer (score 85, accepted):

After executing the below regex, your answer is in the first capture.

```
/^(.*?)\.txt/
```

Comment: Nice, beat me to the punch. Note that depending on what regex engine you're using, you might not need the wrapping `/`

Comment: Yes, good point.  I am in Vim, Ruby, or JS 24/7 and I always forget about this >.< Thanks :)

Answer (score 67):

This matches everything up to ".txt" (without including it):

`^.*(?=(\.txt))`

Comment: Let's says you want the http://url.com/users/2 in http://url.com/users/2/some/stuff/after, how do you also include the matcher ?

Answer (score 16):

You could just do ...

```
(.*?)\.txt
```

[tested here..](http://www.debuggex.com/)

Comment: Won't work for 2 reasons: You're not escaping the `.`, and your `.*` is greedy. What about abctxt? (abc, instead of no match) and abc.txt.txt? (abc.txt, instead of abc)

Comment: +1, this is actually better than my answer as I didn't actually need the `^` in my regex ( was redundant ).

Answer (score 6):

```
^(.*)text
```

this worked for me but **I was actually trying to get everything after the string too**. The first part of the expression should answer your question.

```
^(.*)text([\s\S]*)$
```

where `^(.*)` takes all before and including the text, while `([\s\S]*)$` takes all after and including the text. Tested it at [regexr.com/6cpqg](https://regexr.com/6cpqg).

References:

- above answers among other online sources
- https://regexland.com/regex-match-after-character/

Answer (score 2):

Up to and including `txt` you would need to change your regex like so:

```
^(.*?\\.txt)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
((\n.*){0,3})(.*)\W*\.txt
```

This will select all the content before the particular word ".txt" including any context in different lines up to 3 lines

Comment: What question are you answering? What is the purpose of `\W*`? Why all these useless capture groups?

Comment: Good answer bro. This matches symbols too.