# Match and remove Text before sentence in REGEX?

Tags: python, regex

If I have the following sentence structure:

```
string = '''welcome to our first meeting on talks to do with famous people, this time we are holding it on 1st January 2023 (see website details) 
 <<John Smith, Youtube>> 
I'm having a great day today 
<<Jane Doe, Google>> 
I'm going to the gym later 
<<Speaker>>
Time for people to speak 
<<Beff Jezos>> 
Buy something from my online shop. You might like it'''
```

How can i match and remove the text before the first << - so this means the resulting string is:

```
result_string =  '''<<John Smith, Youtube>> 
I'm having a great day today 
<<Jane Doe, Google>> 
I'm going to the gym later 
<<Speaker>>
Time for people to speak 
<<Beff Jezos>> 
Buy something from my online shop. You might like it'''
```

I have tried a positive lookahead with this regex:

`(.*)(?<=(see website for details)`

But this causes an error in the regex engines as it says it cannot capture all text before the <<.

(see website for details) may change over time, so a match prior to << is more robust.

Any help appreciated.

Fore reference I am using the following Python package:

`import re`
`re.sub(string, pattern, '')` -> empty string as replacement thus removing sentence

Comment: Why is this tagged `nsregularexpression`?

Comment: `string[string.index('<<'):]` simple, any reason for using regex?

Comment: @ScottHunter - removed tagg

Comment: @deadshot is there a regex way of this as string.index may pick up more than one (not be greedy as usual regex)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regular Expression to select everything before and up to a particular text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18413204/regular-expression-to-select-everything-before-and-up-to-a-particular-text)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This regex should work:

`re.search(r"(<<[\s\S]*)", string).group(1)`

`\s` is a whitespace character, and `\S` is a non-whitespace character, so it matches everything an unlimited number of times (because of the `*`)

Answer (score -1):

Your pattern is missing a closing bracket:

```
pattern = r'(.*)(?<=(see website details))'
```

The order of arguments in your re.sub expression is wrong

```
re.sub(pattern, '', string)
```

works almost fine (There is an additional '\n' at the beginning which can be fixed easily.

The suggested usage of string.index('<<') shoul work though, since it returns the index of the first occurrence.